# Double one-to-many in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, relation

I have a problem with double relation of type one-to-many in Entity Framework code first.
Look picture:
http://i43.tinypic.com/5u2x03.png

In class Club I have:

```
public virtual ICollection<Mecz> Hosts{ get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Mecz> Gests{ get; set; }
```

In class Match:

```
public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
```

When update-database I have 3 foreign keys, but I think it should be only 2. There is any special method to do this relation to work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by myself. 
Below my answer, maybe someone need it.

**Match Class:**

```
    public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchID { get; set; }

    public int HostID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HostID")]
    public virtual Club Hosts{ get; set; }

    public int GestID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GestID")]
    public virtual Club Gests{ get; set; }

}
```

**Club Class:**

```
    public class Club
{
    public int ClubID { get; set; }

    public string ClubName{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> Host{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Match> Gest{ get; set; }
}
```

**And in the MyDbContext in OnModelCreating I added code below:**

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Host)
        .WithMany(x => x.Host)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Gest)
        .WithMany(x => x.Gest)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Entity Framework Power Tools to see what EF thinks of your setup.

http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/10/ef-power-tools-beta4

Right-click on your data context class and do Entity Framework-View Entity Data Model.

It might help if you had navigation properties on Mecz, and also put in the Id properties.

```
public class Mecz {
    public int HostAtId{get; set;}
    public virtual Club HostAt{get; set;}
    public int GestAtId{get; set;}
    public virtual Club GestAt{get; set;}
}
```

Then you don't need to have Club in Match: you can say

```
Match.Gest.GestAt
```